# Regular expression to match certain string pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string patterns like `name1|value1`, `name1|value1,name2|value2`, `name1|` and `name1|value1,`. I have to have Regular expression to find the given pattern is true or false

Input and output would be

```
"name1|value1" -> true
"name1|value1,name2|value2"  -> true
"name1|" -> false
"name1|value1," -> false
"name1|value1,name2" -> false
"name1|value1,name2|" -> false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple: `^\w+\|\w+(,\w+\|\w+)*$`

The first portion, `^\w+\|\w+` looks to make sure the string starts with at least 1 completed *`name|value`* pair.

Then the second portion, `(,\w+\|\w+)*` says that same pattern may repeat infinitely as long as there is a comma between the first pair and all subsequent pairs. (*Although, the asterisk quantifies that the second portion of the pattern may not occur at all.*)

Finally the `$` says that the string must end matching this pattern. (I.e., this pattern cannot only match part of the string. It must match the entire string because of the `^` and `$`.)

To format this pattern for javascript, simply throw a forward slashes on both ends, so: `/^\w+\|\w+(,\w+\|\w+)*$/` The pattern should not require any flags.

It is worth noting, if you need to match more complex names/values that are outside the character range of `\w`, then you should replace all `\w`s with `[Some Character Set(s)]`.

Answer (score 2):

If your have multiple pairs to check, you can apply your regex on splitted string elements with an `every` function:

```js
isValidPairs = function(str) {
  return str.split(',').every(function(elt) {
    return /^\w+\|\w+$/.test(elt);
  });
}

pairsArr = ["nam1|val1", "nam1|val1,name2|val2", "nam1|", "nam1|val1,", "nam1|val1,name", "nam1|val1,name|"];
pairsArr.forEach(function(str) {
  console.log('%s: %s:', str, isValidPairs(str));
});
```